# Django; squashmigrations and circular dependencies

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have a Django project with multiple apps, many of which contain lots of migration files. I am attempting to squash these one app at a time using the `squashmigrations` command, however doing so causes a `CircularDepencdyError`. The Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/) advise breaking out one of the keys in the circular dependency to resolve the error, but the error does not specify this level of detail. With thousands of lines of migration code to sift through, I am feeling stuck.

Does anyone have experience of solving this sort of issue or know of some best practices or tips on what to look for?

Comment: How about deleting the existing migration files and creating them anew from the beginning?

Comment: Well, that works! Seems to easy to be true - is there any danger in doing this?

Comment: You will also have to empty the migration table(s) in your DB. If you can do that on your live version, if you have one, there is no risk involved.

Comment: One disadvantage of re-creating migrations is - obviously - that you cannot rollback your db (without reverting the deletion of original migrations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As recommended by Sebastian, the fix to this circular dependency mess:

- delete migration files from project directory
- remove migration entries from the `django_migrations` database table
- run `makemigrations` - Django creates new migration files
- run `migrate --fake` as you should already have the tables in the database

After doing this, I was able to get `manage.py test` working like a charm.

Comment: If you have data migrations, you need to recreate it after run makemigratios

Comment: If you have any operations such as `RunSQL` or `RunPython` they will be lost using this method. `squashmigrations` avoids this